# Inset Coordinates Adjustment

Tags: graphics

I have six graphs (each roughly fits in a circle with radius 2 at the origin) which I want to combine placing one above the other and then place text on them. I am trying to use `Inset` as in the following example and the results are utterly unpredictable, `PlotRange` makes no sense and `PlotRange->All` does not work. Moreover, I would have expected (and would like) the first graph (disk 1) to use the same coordinates are the final one, the wrapping graphic the coordinates of which the text uses. Any ideas? (Using Ma 10.1)

Example code:

```
Graphics[{
  Table[
   Inset[
    Graphics[{
      Disk[{0, 0}, 2], White, Text[j, {0, 1.5}]
     }, Axes -> True,
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0]
    , {0, 0}, {0, 4 (j - 1)}, 2], {j, 6}],
  Gray, Text["Some Text 1", {.4, .4}],
  Text["Some Text 2", {.4, .2}]
  }, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, -11}},
 Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the function `txt`? Side note: use ` for inline code such as `inline code`. Otherwise, indent your code with four spaces (or click on the `{}` icon).

Comment: Yes, changed `txt` to `Text`, sorry.

Comment: @anderstood, how can I change the coordinates of circles 2 through 6 inside a `Show`? I tried `Table[
 {Disk[{0, 0}, 2], White, 
   txt[j, {0, 1.5}]} /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y - 2 j}
 , {j, 6}]` and variants of it but it does not work.

Comment: Pardon me, I don't understand *I would have expected (and would like) the first graph (disk 1) to use the same coordinates are the final one, the wrapping graphic the coordinates of which the text uses.*  Would you please try stating that differently or providing some kind of example?

Comment: @NicholasG I had interpreted "above each other" as "on top of each other" (superimposed). My bad.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, suppose the first of the six graphs had a point at (1,1). After displaying all six graphs, I would like the statement `Point[{1,1}]` to produce a point that is superimposed with the first one. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Closing the question would be most unhelpful. Using your comment I have managed to align the circles of my example. Applying the same principles to my intended graph still does not let the two coordinate systems align. Maybe I am looking for a way to combine graphs other than `Inset` so that the inner and outer coordinate systems can match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Graphics[{Translate[{Opacity[.5, Pink], Disk[{0, 0}, 2], 
          Opacity[1, Purple], Text[# + 1, {0, 1.5}]}, {0, -4 #}] & /@ Range[0, 5], 
  Cyan, Text["Some Text 1", {.5, .5}], Text["Some Text 2", {.5, .1}]},
  PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One problem. Each circle should have its own `Graphics` wrapper to simulate the fact that I will be using other graphics, already produced. I do not see how that would work with `Translate`. If you could wrap `Opacity ... Disk... Text...` inside a `Graphics` maybe that would work.

Comment: @NicholasG, you can use `Graphics[...][[1]]` with `Translate`. For example, `Graphics[{Translate[
     Graphics[{Opacity[.5, Pink], Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Opacity[1, Purple],
         Text[# + 1, {0, 1.5}]}][[1]], {0, -4 #}] & /@ Range[0, 5], 
  Cyan, Text["Some Text 1", {.5, .5}], Text["Some Text 2", {.5, .1}]},
  PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1}]`. See also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136588/125) for a similar use of `Translate`.

Comment: Fabulous, this works. Why do we have to pass the first element of prior graphics to `Translate` instead of the prior graphic itself?

Comment: @NicholasG, the first argument of `Translate` has to be a graphics primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Let us look at your graphics with a few modification to improve the visibility of the elements that are displayed.

```
Graphics[
  {Table[
     Inset[
       Graphics[
         {GrayLevel[.8], Disk[{0, 0}, 2],
          White, Text[j, {.5, -1}]},
         Axes -> True,
         PlotRangePadding -> 0,
         ImagePadding -> 0],
       {0, 0}, {0, 4 (j - 1)}, 2],
     {j, 6}],
   Text["Some Text 1", {.4, .4}],
   Text["Some Text 2", {.4, .2}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {1, -11}},
   Axes -> True,
   AxesLabel -> {"outer-x", "outer-y"},
   AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1},
   ImagePadding -> {{20, 50}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image: disks]

There is nothing at all to complain about in the resulting graphics. Everything is displayed in exactly in the position that was specified for it.

All elements specified in the outer `Graphics` expression, including the six disks, appear correctly placed in the outer coordinate system. All elements specified in the `Inset` expression appear correctly placed in the local coordinate system of their inset `Graphics` expression and are scaled to double size in the outer coordinate system because you specified a scale of 2 for them.

Comment: Bravo! Then, the question becomes what is the correct scaling factor to use so the coordinates for the first graph become those of the outer system. I would have thought 1 might work but no, it ends up being 4. Why? That the width of the inner graph is four and so it should take four units of the outer system? I suppose I should give up on `PlotRange->All` just working.