# How to plot paired smooth histogram/distribution plots?

Tags: plotting, distributions, histograms, charts

I've been trying to get paired distribution (aka "violin") plots like those shown below for a few hours, but all my attempts have failed.

[image]

The key features here are

1. *paired* smooth histograms/distribution plots with a common *vertical* abscissa and divergent *horizontal* ordinates;
2. different fill colors for the two subplots;

The closest *Mathematica* has are `DistributionChart`s, but these plots are not paired (i.e. they are always symmetrical).

---

I first tried `SmoothHistogram`, but it appears that there's no simple way to get a `SmoothHistogram` with a vertical abscissa.

Next I tried `PairedSmoothHistogram`, but I can't manage to assign different fill colors to the two sides.

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0];
 Quiet[
  PairedSmoothHistogram[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100]
   , RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100]
   , AspectRatio -> Automatic
   , Axes -> {False, True}
   , Ticks -> None
   , Spacings -> 0
   , ImageSize -> 30
   , Filling -> Axis
   ]
  , OptionValue::nodef
  ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I tried a combination of `SmoothKernelDistribution` and either `ListPlot`, `ParametricPlot` or `ContourPlot`, but this won't work because neither `ParametricPlot` nor `ContourPlot` accepts a `Fill` option, and I can't figure out how to get `ListPlot` to fill the spaces between the curves and the vertical axis.

For example,

```
violin[data1_, data2_, rest___] := Module[
  {  d1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data1]
   , d2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data2]
   , x
   , xrange
  }, xrange = {x, Sequence @@ (#[data1, data2] & /@ {Min, Max})}
   ; ParametricPlot[ {{-PDF[d1, x], x}, {PDF[d2, x], x}}
                   , Evaluate@xrange
                   , rest
                   , PlotRange -> All
                   , Axes -> {None, True}
                   , Ticks -> None
                   , PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, None}
                   ]
];

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0];
 violin[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100],
        RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100],
        ImageSize -> 30
       ]
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I didn't expect this would be so hard.  My brain is now fried.

Does anyone know how one does this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is something using a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html)

```
Module[{c = 0},
 half[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, data_, metadata_] := (c++;   
   Map[Reverse[({0, Mean[{xmin, xmax}]} + # {1, (-1)^c})] &, 
    First@Cases[
      First@Cases[InputForm[SmoothHistogram[data, Filling -> Axis]], 
        gc_GraphicsComplex :> Normal[gc], ∞], 
      p_Polygon, ∞], {2}])]
```

(thanks to @halirutan for reminding me about how to do closures in WL).

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {4, 2, 100}];

DistributionChart[data, BarSpacing -> -1, ChartElementFunction -> half]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks like it has the right areas as I inserted `data[[1, 1, All]] = 0.5 data[[1, 1, All]] + 2;` and it looks like it is supposed to look.

Comment: What's the rationale for `p_Polygon :> p`?  (I get the same results if I replace it with just `p_Polygon`.)

Comment: Oh  its not needed, just something I forgot to clean up, during some test I was doing.  I will change it now.

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** Using `GeometricTransformation`s to post-process `SmoothHistogram` outputs:

```
ClearAll[halfSH, pairedSH]
halfSH[side : (Left | Right) : Right][data_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{i = 1, tr = If[side === Left, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}], Identity], 
   col = If[side === Left, Blue, Red]}, 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[SmoothHistogram[#, Automatic, "PDF", o, 
   Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Lighter@col, PlotStyle -> col][[1]], 
      Composition[TranslationTransform[{i++, 0}], tr, ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]]], 
     FilterRules[{o}, Options[Graphics]]] & /@ data]

halfSH[side : (Left | Right) : Right][data_, bwkernel__, 
  o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{i = 1, tr = If[side === Left, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}], Identity], 
   col = If[side === Left, Blue, Red]}, 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[SmoothHistogram[#, bwkernel, o, Filling -> Axis, 
   FillingStyle -> Lighter@col, PlotStyle -> col][[1]], 
     Composition[TranslationTransform[{i++, 0}], tr, ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]]], 
     FilterRules[{o}, Options[Graphics]]] & /@ data]

pairedSH[bw_: Automatic, df_: "PDF"][{d1_, o1 : OptionsPattern[]}, 
 {d2_, o2 : OptionsPattern[]},  o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Show[halfSH[Left][d1, bw, df, o1], halfSH[][d2, bw, df, o2], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1 + Length@d1}, Automatic}, o, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[Length@d1], 
     Automatic}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

**Examples:**

```
{data1, data2} = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, #], {4, 1000}] & /@ {2, 1};

pairedSH[][{data1}, {data2}]
```

[image]

```
pairedSH[{"Adaptive", 0.3, .5}][{data1, FillingStyle->Lighter[Cyan], PlotStyle->Green}, 
 {data2, FillingStyle -> Lighter@Orange, PlotStyle -> Red}]
```

[image]

**Original post:**

```
{data1, data2} = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, #], {4, 1000}] & /@ Range[2];

cedf1 = ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity", "Shape" -> "SingleSided"];
cedf2 = ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity", "Shape" -> "FlippedSingleSided"];

Show[DistributionChart[data1, ChartStyle -> Yellow, BarSpacing -> 2, 
      ChartElementFunction -> cedf1, ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}], 
 DistributionChart[data2, ChartStyle -> Red, BarSpacing -> 2, 
  ChartElementFunction -> cedf2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The OP stated "Next I tried PairedSmoothHistogram, but I can't manage to assign different fill colors to the two sides."

Comment: oops, thank you @David.

Comment: Wow! That is both compact and understandable.

Comment: Uh, maybe I spoke too soon.  My comment still holds but...the areas under the curves should all be equal and they are not.  Can that be adjusted?  It looks like they are all scaled to the same height rather than the same area.

Comment: Great function with "halfSH". I use it but I don't succeed to include the bandwith option in SmoothHistogram.

Comment: @Porty, great point.Updated adding a _bspec_ argument.

Comment: @JimB,  the updated version, though not as compact as the original, has equal areas under the curves.

Comment: Very nice!  (And still pretty compact!)

Answer (score 8):

I just followed your approach but rather created tables of the density and associated x-values.  I added a `shift` parameter to `violin` to allow the placement of each pair of probability density estimates.

```
violin[data1_, data2_, shift_] := 
 Module[{d1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data1],
   d2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data2], x, xrange},
  {xmin1, xmax1} = MinMax[data1];
  {xmin2, xmax2} = MinMax[data2];
  xrange1 = xmax1 - xmin1;
  xrange2 = xmax2 - xmin2;
  (* Create a table of the density values along with the associated x value *)
  pdf1 = Table[{-PDF[d1, x] + shift, x}, {x, xmin1 - 0.2 xrange1, 
     xmax1 + 0.2 xrange1, 1.4 xrange1/100}];
  pdf2 = Table[{PDF[d2, x] + shift, x}, {x, xmin2 - 0.2 xrange2, 
     xmax2 + 0.2 xrange2, 1.4 xrange2/100}];
  (* Construct violin graphic *)
  Show[Graphics[{Darker[Green], EdgeForm[Darker[Green]], 
     Polygon[pdf1]}],
   Graphics[{Orange, EdgeForm[Orange], Polygon[pdf2]}]]]

(* Generate some data *)
data11 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
data12 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 1], 100];
data21 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 100];
data22 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 1.5], 100];

Show[ListPlot[{{-1, 3}}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, -8},
  Ticks -> {{{0, "A"}, {2, B}}, Automatic},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-8, 10}}, PlotStyle -> White],
 violin[data11, data12, 0],
 violin[data21, data22, 2],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Violin plot]

Answer (score 6):

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000];
GraphicsRow[{
  Rotate[Graphics[SmoothHistogram[data1, 
     PlotStyle -> Red, 
     Filling -> Axis,
     PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, Automatic}]], π/2],
  Rotate[Graphics[SmoothHistogram[data2, PlotStyle -> Green,
     Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, Automatic}]], -π/
    2]},
 Spacings -> {-234, 5}
 ]
```

[image]

(You may need to flip one distribution to keep the orientation of the vertical axes the same for the two plots.)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

> *I tried PairedSmoothHistogram, but I can't manage to assign different fill colors to the two sides.*

It turns out that `FillingStyle` option setting can be a `Function` so we can inject the two colors using an appropriate `Function` as the value of this option.

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dd1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 100];
dd2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
options = {Axes -> {False, True}, Ticks -> None, Filling -> Axis,
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.005], Gray], Spacings -> 0};

PairedSmoothHistogram[dd1, dd2, 
 FillingStyle -> Module[{i = 1}, ({{Red, Blue}[[i++]], #} &)], options]
```

[image]

An alternative, and less convenient, approach is to post-process the `PairedSmoothHistogram` output

```
Module[{i = 1}, PairedSmoothHistogram[dd1, dd2, options] /. 
 p_Polygon :> {{ Opacity[1, Blue], Opacity[1, Red]}[[i++]], p}]
```

which gives the same output.

This method also works for multiple data pairs using a longer list of colors:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[c, RandomInteger[{1, 3}]], 
    500], {k, 2}, {c, 4}];
options = {Axes -> {False, True}, Ticks -> None, Filling -> Axis, Spacings -> 0,
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Thin, White]};

colors = Opacity[.5, #] & /@ {Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Yellow, Cyan, Pink};

PairedSmoothHistogram[##& @@ data, 
 FillingStyle -> Module[{i = 1}, ({colors[[i++]], #} &)], options]
```

[image]

**Step 2:**

> *paired smooth histograms/distribution plots with a common vertical abscissa and divergent horizontal ordinates*

To get a chart that looks like a `DistributionChart` we can  (1) use `PairedSmoothHistogram` on individual pairs and (2) combine them with appropriate translations.

The function `pshListF` creates a list of paired histograms from a data set with multiple data pairs. The function `displaceF` below (slightly modified version from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136588/125)) performs the necessary translations.

```
ClearAll[pshListF, displaceF]
pshListF[data_, colors_: {Red, Blue}][o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{d = Transpose[data]}, PairedSmoothHistogram[##, 
     FillingStyle -> Module[{i = 1}, ({{Red, Blue}[[i++]], #} &)], o] & @@@ d]

displaceF[p : {__Graphics}, labels_: Automatic, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{d = Accumulate[PlotRange[#][[1, 2]] & /@ p], 
   labeledticks = If[labels == Automatic, Range[Length@p], 
     Thread[{Range[Length@p], labels}]]}, 
  Show[Graphics[Translate[#[[1]], {#2, 0}] & @@@ Transpose[{p, d}]], 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> {{0, 1 + Length@p}, Automatic}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {labeledticks, Automatic}}, o]]
```

Examples:

```
displaceF[pshListF[data][ options]]
```

[image]

```
displaceF[pshListF[data][ options], {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[14, "Panel"]}]
```

[image]